# .htaccess : One directory goes to https, everything else goes http

Tags: .htaccess

This seems simple enough, but the documentation and search results on mod_rewrite are a bit lacking.  In the interest of saving time, can someone explain to me the best way to direct my traffic?

If the url is `/show/checkout` I want `https://servername.com/show/checkout`.  If the url is anything else, I want it to go to `http://servername.com/show/whatever`.

I've got mod_rewrite enabled.  I am able to send all traffic to https, but I haven't succesfully filtered out /show/checkout traffic.  This doesn't work because there is some insecure images/scripts that are causing security warnings in some browsers.

Thanks!

Current .htaccess that sends all traffic to https:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 65.208.151.

Options -Indexes

AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1

DirectoryIndex index.cgi

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://myserver.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^show/product/(.*)$ ?content=product;title=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)/(.*)$ ?content=$1;nth=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ ?content=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^place/order$ ?email=order [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .htm$ /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://myserver.com/$1 [R,L]
```

doesn't do anything, since URI's used to match on won't start with a `/`. Not just that, this rule is simply a redirect loop.

Remove that and try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !show/checkout
RewriteCond $1 !^show/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://servname.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^show/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://servname.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This worked, and taught me what I wanted to understand about how mod_rewrite works.